# how to convert the date stored in a variable in to a date formate in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is my jquery code, I want to compare the date pick by user with my gstdate.

```
$('#FromDate').on('blur', function() {
  var fromdate = $('#FromDate').val();
  var gstdate = "1-7-2017";
  var gd = new Date('d-m-Y', gstdate);

  if (fromdate <= gst) {
    //do something..
  } else {
    //do something..
  }
});
```

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to date in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert to the fromDate into date variable as you did with gstDate

```
$('#FromDate').on('blur', function() {
  var fromdate = new Date("d-m-Y", $('#FromDate').val());
  var gstdate = "1-7-2017";
  var gd = new Date('d-m-Y', gstdate);

  if (fromdate <= gst) {
    //do something..
  } else {
    //do something..
  }
});
```

Comment: var gstdate = "1-7-2017"; 
 var gd = new Date('d-m-Y',gstdate); This code does not converting my gstdate in a date format. In console I have got an error : invalid date

Comment: Thanks, it worked ! Still in the date comparison having trouble using this way [ if(fromdate <= gst) ].

Answer (score 0):

You can try [momentJs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

I hope I've helped you!

Comment: Here I want to convert statically assigned date in to a date format. i.e. var gd = "01-07-2017".

Comment: I corrected the answer, would you please try to see it?

Comment: Yes It helped ! Thanks you @Tran Audi

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#FromDate').on('blur', function() {
  var gstdate = new Date("1-7-2017"); //date object required
  var fromdate = new Date($(this).val());
    console.log(gstdate);
  if (fromdate.getTime() <= gstdate.getTime()) {// getTime() returns the number of milliseconds
    console.log('hello');
  } else {
  console.log('bye');
  }
});
```

Comment: having an error log : fromdate.getTime() is not a function.

Comment: Please refer this [https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp] in this **getTime()** is a function 
For that **date object** is required and your gst date is not in formatted it should be **mm-dd-yyyy**